# running site on IIS server gives an error

Tags: iis-7, codeigniter-3

I'm uploading my site on IIS server and then it gives an error 500(Internal Server Error), when i'm trying to create new user.
But the same code is perfectly run on localhost.

I think the error is because of web.config file.

I'm using Apache server on local machine. for hosting I'm using IIS server.

here is my web.config file code :

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
```

please help me,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) on the IIS server.

**STEPS**:

1. Logon to the IIS server (either; console or RDP).
2. Download the MSI installer file the corresponds to your server's platform; [x86](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615138) or [x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615137).
3. Double-click on the MSI installer file. The installation wizard should walk you though the steps.
4. Once you're done, try to reload the site from your browser.

Comment: I'm totally new for IIS server, will you please explain how can I do that.

Comment: But some of the functionalities are working in site, If I tried to create a department it will work, but while creating new user or customer, it gives an error.

Comment: @Quleiss.G: You've edited your question now. Are you using IIS or Apache? Your question subject contradicts the description? If using Apache, why are using web.config? You can use mod_rewrite in Apache and set the rules in .htaccess

Comment: I'm useing apache on local system, and for that i use .htaccess file. but I'm hosting my site on IIS server.

Comment: On localhost it runs fine. but not on IIS server

Comment: @Quleiss.G: In that case, I believe your question doesn't belong here since it is not related to programming. It is related to "How to host a PHP site on IIS with URL Re-write" You should find better answers on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the URL Rewrite module via Microsoft Web Platform installer first. After that, select the website/application in question and it will appear within the 'Features view' of IIS. You can then set it up as needed.

Comment: Which module I have to install.

Comment: The URL Rewrite module like Khalid T. said above. I'll edit it for more readable instructions.